# PHP $_FILES Upload not Working

Tags: php, file

My issue is when I try to echo out any file properties, from the file that was uploaded, it doesn't work.

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<form method="POST"> <input type="file" name="uploaded" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom: 10px"> </form>
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php echo $_FILES['uploaded']['type'] ?>
```

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enctype` should be on the `<form>` element

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php echo $_FILES['uploaded']['type'] ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the best!